# Powershell, For vs Foreach when moving XML Elements

Tags: xml, powershell

I have a loop that moves XML Elements from one spot to another.  It works fine with a For loop, but with a Foreach loop it iterates forever.  Is this just an unfortunate clash of implementations (XMLElement vs foreach loop) or is there a better practice I'm missing?  I'm by no means an expert with the System.Xml library.

**Demo script**

```
$xmlDocOriginalValue = [xml]@"
<root>
    <dir Id = "source" >
        <file Id = "1" />
        <file Id = "2" />
    </dir>
    <dir Id = "destination" >
        <file Id = "3" />
        <file Id = "4" />
    </dir>
</root>
"@

$xmlDoc = $xmlDocOriginalValue.Clone()
$files = $xmlDoc.SelectNodes('//file')
$destination = $xmlDoc.SelectSingleNode('//dir[@Id="destination"]')

# Move "files" from source to destination using both a "for" and a "foreach" loop

Write-Host "For loop"
Write-Host "XML before: $($xmlDoc.OuterXml)"
for($i = 0; $i -lt $files.count; $i++)
{
    Write-Host ("Iteration "+$i + ", " + $files[$i].OuterXml)
    $destination.AppendChild($files[$i]) | Out-Null
}
Write-Host "XML after: $($xmlDoc.OuterXml)"

# Reset and try with a foreach loop
$xmlDoc = $xmlDocOriginalValue.Clone()
$files = $xmlDoc.SelectNodes('//file')
$destination = $xmlDoc.SelectSingleNode('//dir[@Id="destination"]')

Write-Host "`nForeach loop"
Write-Host "XML before: $($xmlDoc.OuterXml)"
$i = 0
foreach($file in $files)
{
    Write-Host ("Iteration "+$i + ", " + $file.OuterXml)
    $destination.AppendChild($file) | Out-Null
    $i++
}
Write-Host "XML after: $($xmlDoc.OuterXml)"
```

**Output**

```
For loop
XML before: <root><dir Id="source"><file Id="1" /><file Id="2" /></dir><dir Id="destination"><file Id="3" /><file Id="4" /></dir></root>
Iteration 0, <file Id="1" />
Iteration 1, <file Id="2" />
Iteration 2, <file Id="3" />
Iteration 3, <file Id="4" />
XML after: <root><dir Id="source"></dir><dir Id="destination"><file Id="1" /><file Id="2" /><file Id="3" /><file Id="4" /></dir></root>

Foreach loop
XML before: <root><dir Id="source"><file Id="1" /><file Id="2" /></dir><dir Id="destination"><file Id="3" /><file Id="4" /></dir></root>
Iteration 0, <file Id="1" />
Iteration 1, <file Id="2" />
Iteration 2, <file Id="3" />
Iteration 3, <file Id="4" />
Iteration 4, <file Id="1" />
Iteration 5, <file Id="2" />
Iteration 6, <file Id="3" />
Iteration 7, <file Id="4" />
Iteration 8, <file Id="1" />
Iteration 9, <file Id="2" />
Iteration 10, <file Id="3" />
Iteration 11, <file Id="4" />
Iteration 12, <file Id="1" />
Iteration 13, <file Id="2" />
Iteration 14, <file Id="3" />
Iteration 15, <file Id="4" />
Iteration 16, <file Id="1" />
Iteration 17, <file Id="2" />
Iteration 18, <file Id="3" />
...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From quick experimentation it is indeed a clash, in the sense of attempting to modify the iterator while in the loop. That is, you are initially selecting all  elements--*including those in the destination*. One would think that should be harmless but apparently not. To prove this, change your selection of nodes to this:

```
$files = $xmlDoc.SelectNodes('//dir[@Id="source"]/file')
```

... wherein you select only those file nodes in the source. (After all, the ones in the destination do not need to be included since they are already where you want them.) With that change, the code executes as expected.

Here is another variation that will work, going back to your original selector. I changed only the three lines marked with octothorps (#############) to grab the nodes then modify the XML in separate steps:

```
# Reset and try with a foreach loop
$xmlDoc = $xmlDocOriginalValue.Clone()
$files = $xmlDoc.SelectNodes('//file')
$destination = $xmlDoc.SelectSingleNode('//dir[@Id="destination"]')

Write-Host "`nForeach loop"
Write-Host "XML before: $($xmlDoc.OuterXml)"

$i = 0
$list = @()                                    ##############
foreach($file in $files) { $list += $file }    ##############
foreach($item in $list)                        ##############
{ 
    Write-Host ("Iteration "+$i + ", " + $file.OuterXml)
    $destination.AppendChild($item) | Out-Null 
    $i++
}
Write-Host "XML after: $($xmlDoc.OuterXml)"
```

Comment: Aha, that makes it clear.  I'm amazed that my query from a previous line is getting reevaluated by the loop, which explains the infinite loop.  Not the first time I've seen PowerShell bends the rules of time ;)  The collection returned by SelectNodes must be somehow special vs the $list you created, above. If I get curious I'll interrogate it. Thanks!

Comment: Yes, I would be interested to know what you uncover!